# What is the function of a for(;;) loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop

I am trying to read data from an ifstream. I am using code as a reference that my prof gave me. I am confused as to what the for(;;) is doing and when the loop ends. I understand for loop basics but I have never seen this notation before.

```
//------------------------------- buildTree ----------------------------------
// To build a tree, read strings from a line, terminating when "$$" is
// encountered. Since there is some work to do before the actual insert that is
// specific to the client problem, it's best that building a tree is not a 
// member function. It's a global function. 

void buildTree(BinTree& T, ifstream& infile) {
    string s;

    for (;;) {
        infile >> s;
        cout << s << ' ';
        if (s == "$$") break;                // at end of one line
        if (infile.eof()) break;             // no more lines of data
        NodeData* ptr = new NodeData(s);     // NodeData constructor takes string
        // would do a setData if there were more than a string

        bool success = T.insert(ptr);
        if (!success)
            delete ptr;                       // duplicate case, not inserted 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a for has 3 parts:

1. do **befor** the loop starts (most of the time this is `int i = 0`)
2. condition **if** the loop **runs**
3. parts executed **after** 1 run through the loop

a for(;;) means it doesn't have a condition when to stop so it's **endless**